# Is it possible to turn a weighted adjacency matrix into an ODE compartment model?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, network-flow

I have an idea for a project that hinges on this idea.

Lets say we have an adjacency matrix of a DiGraph where the i,j entry represents an out-going edge from node i to node j and at this position we have a rate describing how much of something leaves node i to node j in respect to time.

Is there a straight forward way using matrix algebra to convert this matrix to a system of ODEs that describes a multi-compartment model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you graph is represented by the adjacency matrix $A = \{a_{i,j}\}$, such that $a_{i,j} \geq 0$ for all $i \neq j$ and $a_{i,i} = 0$, then you can use the matrix:

$$B = \{b_{i,j}\}$$

where $b_{i,j} = a_{i,j}$ and $\displaystyle b_{j,j} = -\sum_{i=1,i\neq j}^{n} a_{i,j}$.

The ODE system is $\dot{x} = Bx$, where $$\dot{x}_i = \sum_{j=1}^n b_{i,j}x_j.$$

Notice that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\dot{x}_i = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n b_{i,j}x_j = \\
= \sum_{j=1}^nx_j\sum_{i=1}^n b_{i,j} = \sum_{j=1}^nx_j\left(b_{j,j} + \sum_{i=1, i \neq j}^n b_{i,j}\right) = \\
= \sum_{j=1}^nx_j\left(-\sum_{i=1,i\neq j}^{n} a_{i,j} + \sum_{i=1, i \neq j}^n a_{i,j}\right) = 0.$$

This means that the quantity $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$ remains constant at every time since $$\sum_{i=1}^n\dot{x}_i = 0.$$

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb for not realizing this on my own. For some reason I thought you had to convert the adjacency matrix to an incidence matrix but it looks like I was overthinking the problem.

Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Thinking about this, how would you account for flow entering a node since the adjacency matrix only records outgoing edges. Would you have to add the transpose of the adjacency matrix?

Comment: @kilocal yes, I think you should transpose $A$ before doing the job.